# Stop repeating the same code in css

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm fairly new to learning CSS and have been playing with some animation and things.

In my CSS, I have the same thing repeating again and again, but with a difference of 0.1. It's animation-delay: 0.1s, this increases in increments of 0.1s.

Do I have to type the code like I have in my example. Or is there a way I can tell it to increase by 0.1 for the next class? Or should I have done this differently?

The reason is that I wanted to create about 50 of these squares to see what it looks like. I don't really want to type out 50 classes and then change the increments to 0.2 for each class, I would have to change it 50 times. I'm sure there's a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
@keyframes mycolour {
    from {height: 100px;}
    to {height: 150px;}
}

.first, .second, .third, .fourth, .fifth, .sixth, .seventh, .eighth, .ninth, .tenth {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    animation-name: mycolour;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-color: red;

}

.second {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.third {
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.fourth {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.fifth {
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.sixth {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.seventh {
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.eighth {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

.ninth {
    animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

.tenth {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
}



</style>

</head>


<body>

<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
<div class="fourth"></div>
<div class="fifth"></div>
<div class="sixth"></div>
<div class="seventh"></div>
<div class="eighth"></div>
<div class="ninth"></div>
<div class="tenth"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript frankly wuld be a better option. As you have discovered CSS isn't set up to increment like that...especially over many elements.

Comment: A CSS pre-processor like SASS or LESS can make *writing* these things quicker but it still chunks out the same amount of CSS in the end.

Comment: you can use javascript or a css pre-processor like SASS or LESS with an html pre-proc like Jade

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the help. I'll research more about SASS. Javascript is next on the list!

Answer (score 0):

Like someone suggested earlier, javascript is the best option:
If you do happen to learn jquery first this is a simple solution to your problem written in jquery (although its mostly plain ol' javascript).

```js
// CHANGE THE NUMBER 4 IN THE NEXT LINE TO THE NUMBERS OF DIVS YOU HAVE
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
 var div = ".div"+i;
  var value = "."+i+"s";
 $(div).css("animation-delay", value);
}
```

```css
@keyframes mycolour {
    from {height: 100px;}
    to {height: 150px;}
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    animation-name: mycolour;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-color: red;
    animation-delay: .1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
<div class="div3"></div>
<div class="div4"></div>
```